# ZBar SDK iOS: How can I change cancel button text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, text, zbar-sdk

I'm trying to use ZBar SDK and It works perfectly
My only question is how can I change the cancel button text to be multilanguage

This is the code I'm using

```
ZBarReaderViewController *codeReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
codeReader.readerDelegate=self;
codeReader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;


ZBarImageScanner *scanner = codeReader.scanner;
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

[self presentViewController:codeReader animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please stop using `zbar-sdk` for iOS.  Last time I used it, it had a big memory leak problem... and iOS has had native barcode scanning since iOS 7.

Comment: I didn't know that @nhgrif .. Can you give me some direction?

Comment: Erick, [here is an example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42252/avcapturemetadataoutputobjects-wrapper).

Comment: Thanks for replying @nhgrif 
I can move from here now